# need a maintainable Javascript postback pattern for widgets and settings in a dashboard

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, widget, postback

I'm building widgets in a dashboard in ASP MVC, these widgets (charts, mail client, calendar) contain 1) data in the widget and 2) settings about the widget layout, color, position inside that need to be persisted.

*Since the widgets Ajax POST functionality is common, i.e. only data and settings change,*

1. Question 1: Is there a easy/well-baked common javascript
   function/module/framework/design-pattern, how do you do it ?
2. Question 2: Can this code-block/pattern... apply to all the widgets postback, where I can
   change the postback parameters in the function url, and call the same widget?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a custom http Web handlers for your widgets which are called by javascript. On the Web server, your application can identify calls to this handler and handle each widget type as you like it to be handled. This way you can extend this functionality beyond the existing set of widgets which much changes on client side.

Answer (score 0):

one of the arguments in the $.POST is a data parameter.

in the widget request find the attr you seek, and send that to server